# Laravel - Filter a collection by a dynamic field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

The model has 3 fields that are attributes of the model and the 4th field is a dynamic field that is called "fullTitle"

```
[
    {
    "id": 1,
    "hours": 2000,
    "car_id": 3,
    "fullTitle": "Test",
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Car;



class VenderModel extends Model
{
    use TranslationTrait;

    protected $guarded = ['*'];

    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'fullTitle'
    ];


    /**
     * Accessor for dynamic property fullTitle to use as selector name.
     * @param string $locale
     * @return null|string|string[]
     */
    public function getFullTitleAttribute($locale = 'es')
    {
        if (null === $this->hasTranslation()) {
            return trans('errors.No name');
        }

        return preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $this->code.' '. $this->translationOrFirst($locale)->translation);
    }

}



    public function index(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $limit      = $request->input('limit', 25);
        $title      = $request->input('title');

        $query = VenderModel::all();

        $query->when($request->query('title'), function ($q) use ($title) {
            return $q->where('fullTitle', 'like', '%' . $title . '%');
        });

        return response()->json($query, 200);

    }
```

What I'm trying to do is pick up the elements with the fullTitle but doesnt work

Comment: `fullTitle` isn't a DB field, right?

Comment: Are you getting error? If so then provide it to us.

Comment: @Tarasovych its not a db field , it's a dynamic field

Comment: So, you have to "calculate" `fullTitle` for all the entities you want to filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot ask your database to search for something that does not actually exist in the table.

Custom attributes are only called when you ask for the derived property. They cannot be used in the query.

Alternatively, you can grab ALL the rows in memory and then filter it with PHP, but it's not a good way.

Also you can think about storing translation of specific property in related table and then search in database by relation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$collection = VenderModel::get();

$collection->filter(function($item) use($title) {
    return preg_match('/.*'.$title.'.*/', $item->fullTitle) !== false;
});

return response()->json($collection, 200);
```

I think this should solve it. You can't use query on a field that is not actually field in your table, but you should be able to filter it as a collection

Comment: Note: this solution doesn't scale well with big amounts of data. If you want it to scale you basically need to store translations in a different table and use joins, but if you'll have like 100 records it shouldn't matter